# Tiptoi - Update the firmware?

Tags: games, firmware

[Tiptoi Ravensburger](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiptoi) game: How to update the firmware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the free firmware e.g."Update3202.upd" ("2.Datei") including the file "update.upd" (1.Datei) from the [Ravensburger homepage](https://www.ravensburger.de/entdecken/ravensburger-marken/tiptoi/Aktualisierung-der-Firmware/index.html) (Update 2020) to your hard drive.
2. Connect the Tiptoi with the USB cable, turn it on. It will appear as new drive "tiptoi" in your file browser (e.g. Nautilus, Nemo, Thunar).
3. Transfer both update files from your harddrive to your tiptoi drive without changing the names (e.g. in your file browser).
4. Disconnect the Tiptoi from the computer
5. Restart the Tiptoi and the update will be installed.